# Clean up android background thread, handler and looper

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am looking for the best way to clean up a background thread in android. I create the thread the following way:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable () {
        public void  run () {
            Looper.prepare();
            backgroundHandler = new Handler();
            backgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                ....
            }
        });
        Looper.loop();
    }
});
```

It seems like calling Looper.quitSafely() is the way to clean everything up for gc in versions of android 18+, but I have not been able to find a good solution for older versions of android. Before android 18 the only option is the Looper.quit() method which is "unsafe" according to the docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quit()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)

My latest attempt at a solution to this problem is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
    backgroundHandler.getLooper().quitSafely();
} else {

    backgroundHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    backgroundHandler.getLooper().quit();
}
backgroundHandler = null;
```

But I have been getting warnings when running tests:

```
 W/MessageQueue﹕ Handler{40593dd8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{40593dd8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.postEventFromNative(MediaPlayer.java:1522)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I think that it is possible that there are problems with my tests because I am testing a lot of things that are running on background threads (async.) I am using CountDownLatch to wait for the async code to finish running (callback) before ending tests, but I could be missing something.

This makes me question the following code:

```
backgroundHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
backgroundHandler.getLooper().quit();
```

Is there a problem with this way of cleaning up a background thread/handler/looper or a better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I think the real question is what do you mean by cleanup. The garbage collector works automatically,  you don't have to free resources yourself. Having said that a `Thread` will only be garbage collected once it is no longer running. So the Thread will be garbage collected either once it stops on its own or after you cancel it.

Comment: Just a note that while [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) doesn't solve your problem, it does do all the boilerplate thread+looper stuff for you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller By cleanup I mean stop the looper so that the thread will stop and be garbage collected